# Можно ли выбрать данные из трех таблиц стразу?

Tags: php, select, mysql

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста. У меня есть выборка из двух таблиц, можно ли выбирать сразу из трех? Моя выборка выглядит так.

```
   $post_query = mysql_query("SELECT a.*,b.* FROM post a, users b WHERE a.user1='".$myrow["id"]."' AND a.user2!='".$user2["id"]."' AND a.user2=b.id 
    ORDER by a.time_pst DESC");
```

Comment: хоть из десяти. Читайте про [join][1] (впрочем, и ваш "грязный join" тоже сойдёт

[1]:http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/JOIN.html

Comment: @DreamChild прочитал твой коммент как "грязный Джон")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно из сколько угодно, главное указать критерий, по которому "клеить" строки.
Пример: 3 таблицы, users, posts, categories. Пользователь разместил пост и мы хотим получить строку вида | заголовок поста | имя пользователя | название категории.
Делаем запрос:

```
SELECT users.*, posts.*, categories.* 
FROM users, posts, categories 
WHERE
    posts.user_id = user.id AND
    posts.category_id = categories.id
```

Надеюсь понятно ответил. Также можно к таблице приклеить и к users

```
SELECT users.*, posts.*, categories.*, city.* 
FROM users, posts, categories, city 
WHERE
    posts.user_id = user.id AND
    posts.category_id = categories.id AND
    users.city_id = city.id
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, да все понятно ответили.Просто вот написал посты и комментарии к ним, вот хочу еще что бы при загрузки фотографий тоже выборка шла вот из третей таблицы images